# JavaScript: only keep the latest appended element in an array in an efficient way(considering both in runtime and space complexity)

Tags: javascript

so here I have an array, and it continuously append new values from my webpage's newly received data from a GET api. Now, I want to always remain this latest appended value in the array but delete all the previous ones when I have this new value appended, how to solve this question?

Comment: How is this any different from a single scalar variable?

Comment: It's just an regular array or list that append the strings

Comment: So unwrap it from the array. No need for an array if it only ever has 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray=[1,2,3]
myArray.push(4);

var needle=myArray[myArray.length-1];

myArray=[];
myArray.push(needle);

console.log(myArray);
```